# Disconnecting external HDD via USB-A Hub when second drive is connected

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I have a USB powered USB-A 3.0 hub with 4 USB-A 3.0 ports. When I try to connect two HDDs at the same time, first one is disconnecting.

- first is [Toshiba Canvio Basics 2TB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079D3D8NR) USB powered drive connected to USB 3.0 on USB Hub
- second is [LaCie Porsche Design Desktop Drive 4TB](https://www.lacie.com/gb/en/support/desktop-storage/porsche-design-desktop-mac/) external powered drive connected to USB 3.0 on USB Hub

Is my hub faulty or one of the drives draw to much power?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I would guess (the best I can do) that your non-powered drive is drawing too much power.  As mentioned, we don't have enough info.  Different revisions of USB provide different power.  We need the whole picture.  USB 2.0? 3.0?  What drive? etc etc etc

Comment: Edited to include more details.

Comment: Your hub description lacks the information if it is externally powered or not.

Comment: Hub is USB powered.